# How specify more general my .htaccess routing in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule js/jquery.min.js myproject/page/js/jquery.min.js
RewriteRule js/bootstrap.min.js myproject/page/js/bootstrap.min.js
RewriteRule styles/bootstrap.min.css myproject/page/styles/bootstrap.min.css
RewriteRule styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css myproject/page/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css
RewriteRule styles/vinoservice.css myproject/page/styles/vinoservice.css
```

And also for images like that.

And my question is how can i specify a route like: every js/*.js file serving the myproject/page/js/*.js and of course for the styles also? 
Thanks for the helps!

***UPDATE***

I tried this for them:

```
RewriteRule ^js\/.*(.js$) vinoservice/page/js/$1
RewriteRule ^styles\/.*(.css$) vinoservice/page/styles/$1
RewriteRule ^images\/.*(.png$) vinoservice/page/images/$1
RewriteRule ^images\/.*(.jpg$) vinoservice/page/images/$1
```

But not working correctly...but in regex generator says its good for them...interesting...what can be a problem? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be concerned with the extensions if you wish to handle `js/myscript.php` differently, which I doubt you do.

As such, use the following:

```
RewriteRule js/([^/]+)     myproject/page/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule styles/([^/]+) myproject/page/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks a lot....could you tell me waht means the end of the lines? So the L,R = 301?

Comment: You can read more about them [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). They're flags which tell Apache how to handle the rewrite.